# How to verify a public class's static method get called using mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

The pseudo code is like this

```
rc = SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(arg)


public class SomePublicClass {
    private SomePublicClass() {
    }

    public static int myPublicStaticFunc(arg) {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

in UT this doesn't work

```
verify(SomePublicClass, times(1)). myPublicStaticFunc();
```

since this is a public class, how to verify myFunc gets called in mockito in unit test ? If SomePublicClass were a mocked class, this can work.

Comment: I don't understand very much your question, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: does this help you? https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify

Comment: not really, to use mockito you need to mock the object 1st. In my case it's a static method.

Comment: then what you need is to use PowerMock, maybe something like this? https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock

Answer (score 21):

Mocking static methods is available since Mockito 3.4.

See pull request: [Mockito #1013: Defines and implements API for static mocking.](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/1955)

Please note that the fact that this feature is available is not equivalent with recommendation to use it. It is aimed at legacy apps where you cannot refactor the source code.

Having said that:

Test when static method takes no arguments:

```
try (MockedStatic<SomePublicClass> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SomePublicClass.class)) {
    dummyStatic.when(SomePublicClass::myPublicStaticFunc)
               .thenReturn(5);
    // when
    System.out.println(SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc());
    //then
    dummyStatic.verify(            
            SomePublicClass::myPublicStaticFunc, times(1));
}
```

Test when static methods takes arguments:

```
try (MockedStatic<SomePublicClass> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SomePublicClass.class)) {
    dummyStatic.when(() -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()))
               .thenReturn(5);
    // when
    System.out.println(SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(7));
    //then
    dummyStatic.verify(            
            () -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()), times(1));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it was a recent change, but in mockito 4.2, the verify arguments are reversed of the ones listed.  `dummyStatic.verify(() -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()), times(1));`

Comment: @Loren It was a while ago, in 3.7.7, see this pull request: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2173

Answer (score 4):

Since **Mockito-Inline 4.0** the order of parameters for verify has been reversed to match the other verification methods:

Test when static method takes no arguments:

```
try (MockedStatic<SomePublicClass> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SomePublicClass.class)) {
    dummyStatic.when(SomePublicClass::myPublicStaticFunc)
               .thenReturn(5);
    // when
    System.out.println(SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc());
    //then
    dummyStatic.verify(
            SomePublicClass::myPublicStaticFunc,
            times(1)
    );
}
```

Test when static methods takes arguments:

```
try (MockedStatic<SomePublicClass> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SomePublicClass.class)) {
    dummyStatic.when(() -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()))
               .thenReturn(5);
    // when
    System.out.println(SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(7));
    //then
    dummyStatic.verify(
            () -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()),
            times(1)
    );
}
```