# Verify static method calls with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, static-methods

I am trying to verify in a test that a static method is called. I am using Mockito for this purpose.

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006056/how-to-verify-a-public-classs-static-method-get-called-using-mockito). However, the solution suggested in the most upvoted reply is not applicable anymore as the MockedStatic verify method is deprecated.

```
try (MockedStatic<SomePublicClass> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SomePublicClass.class)) {
dummyStatic.when(() -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()))
           .thenReturn(5);
// when
System.out.println(SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(7));
//then
dummyStatic.verify(
        times(1), 
        () -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt())
);
}
```

The alternative is to call

```
verify(dummyStatic).myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt);
```

However, it complains that the method myPublicStaticFunc(int) is undefined for the type
MockedStatic.

What are my alternatives, or what am I missing. Also, I know I can try this using PowerMock, but for the moment, I am trying to get this working using Mockito only.

Comment: What version of `mockito`  do you use. In 3.5.13 it is not deprecated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems that deprecated is `void verify(VerificationMode mode, Verification verification)` while `void verify(Verification verification, VerificationMode mode)` is still fine so you can just use the `verify` method like

```
dummyStatic.verify(
    () -> SomePublicClass.myPublicStaticFunc(anyInt()),
    times(1)
);
```

I've used the following dependency: `testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.12.1"`.

It seems that with `mockito-core` you will not be able to mock this because you'll receive

> The used MockMaker SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks

Comment: Just a little improvement. There is a default method on ```MockedStatic``` interface ```default void verify(Verification verification)``` which calls ```verify(verification, times(1));```