# How to use MockedStatic verify on static methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following mocks for 2 different static method; `UnitConversion.isCompatible()` and `Logging.error()` that are called in my service method.

Here is my test method:

```
myService.demoMethod();


try (MockedStatic<UnitConversion> unitConversion= mockStatic(UnitConversion.class)) {
    unitConversion.verify(never(), () -> UnitConversion.isCompatible(any()));
    UnitConversion.isUnitsCompatible(any());
}


try (MockedStatic<Logging> logging = mockStatic(Logging.class)) {
    logging.verify(times(1), () -> Logging.error(any()));
    Logging.error(any();
}
```

The first method is never called while the second one is called one time when I debug. It is ok, but the test gives "Wanted but not invoked" error for the second method. I am not sure if I should call the static methods in try blocks, because I already call my service method that calls the static methods.

So, how can I verify the static method calls using `MockedStatic` (not powermock, etc)? SHould I call them in try blocks?

**Update:** I use the following approach, but it still gives *"Wanted but not invoked"* error even if breakpoint hit once to the static method called from the service method.

```
// I also try to call the service method under the test here again
demoService.create(request);        

try (MockedStatic<LoggingUtils> mock = mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class)) {
    // as the static method is void, no need to stub and not use "when()" in here

    // I call the service method under the test
    demoService.create(request);

    // verify that the method is being invoked
    mock.verify(times(1), () -> LoggingUtils.error(any(), any()));
}
```

**Update-II:**

***demoService:***

```
public CommandDTO create(final PurchaseRequest request) {
    // code omitted

    addLog();
    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(purchase.getUuid()).build();
}

private void addLog() {
    LoggingUtils.error("error", null);
}
```

***LoggingUtils:***

```
public class LoggingUtils {

    public static void error(String var1, Throwable var2) {
        log.error(getString(var1), var2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify a public class's static method get called using mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006056/how-to-verify-a-public-classs-static-method-get-called-using-mockito)

Comment: @Lesiak Thanks a lot for your helps. Actually I tried many similar approaches, but there are some points that I do not understand. Cı-ould you clarify me about the following issues pls? (I will add my comments to that threat and if I solve then will vote up there and close this thread).

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues in this snippet:

```java
try (MockedStatic<UnitConversion> unitConversionMockStatic = mockStatic(UnitConversion.class)) {
    unitConversionMockStatic.verify(never(), () -> UnitConversion.isCompatible(any()));
    UnitConversion.isUnitsCompatible(any());
}
```

- you verify that the method is being called before calling it
- as you specified that you expect never(), this passes
- you call the method with the argument matcher. This is illegal - you need to call with normal parameter.

Thus, the structure of the test should be

```java
try (MockedStatic<UnitConversion> unitConversionMockStatic = mockStatic(UnitConversion.class)) {
    // if needed, stub the static method with when

    // call the static method (probably indirectly, via service under thest)
    UnitConversion.isUnitsCompatible(10);

    // verify that the method is being invoked
    unitConversionMockStatic.verify(times(1), () -> UnitConversion.isCompatible(any()));
}
```

Note the usage of try-with-resources, MockStatic is no longer in effect when it is closed (which happens when you exit from the try-with-resources block). Thus, you must invoke the method under test (which calls the static method) inside of the try-with-resources block.

Comment: **1.** Many thanks for your helps. Normally I call the service method under the test, then I think I call it on the `UnitConversion.isUnitsCompatible(10);` line instead of calling static method directly. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, and service method under test will call the isUnitsCompatible

Comment: **2.** If 1st is true, then it means I will call my service method in each try block of `MockedStatic`. But I am wondering if I should call my service method under test out of these try block(s). If so, should I call before or after try block(s)?

Comment: You can call some service methods before and after try-with-resources block, but in such case the static method is not patched.

Comment: No, I mean the same service method under the test. Should I call this service method in each try block + after / before that block? Or just in each try block(s) ?

Comment: If you need to patch 2 static methods from different classes (because method under test calls both) use try-with-resources with 2 resources. Thus, both methods will be patched inside the block

Comment: Please see my update, I tried with 2 different option with/without calling the service method before the try block. But still the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Please show the body of method under test and all overloads of `UnitConversion.isCompatible`. I suspect you verify another overload.

Comment: I added and updated the previous method name.

Comment: There is no `error` class taking only a String in the source code you posted. Either you posted incomplete code or you import class from a different package

Comment: DO not worry for that, I just omitted some parts. But ok, I update it.

Comment: By the way, if it is better to use PowerMock, you can also post its example. I have really no idea :(

Comment: You are still veryfing a call to non-existing method - which means your code fails to compile. These are details, but they DO matter.

Comment: Ok I also added `any()` parameter, but why do you concentrate parameters? The issues is not that and I just wanted to omit some parts for clarity. Just concentrate on the problem pls, there is no problem ragarding to that part. Because normally the static method is called without any problem.

Comment: I pasted your code to my IDE and it passes without any issue. I'll refrain from further comments until I see a reproducible example, not a one shortened "for clarity". BTW, you are completely misusing MDC.

Comment: I tried all of combination for your suggestion but still not works when I do not call static method in try block. That is the problem I explained to you.